# ruby setup for chess-like game

Tags: ruby, ajax, sinatra, server-sent-events

I'm going to start a pet-project, bringing [this board game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoridor) into web. For simplicity, imagine pvp chess instead.

I have very little expeirence with this kind of async programming. The only one - I wrote a simple chat with sinatra, using its streaming features.

I've got two closely related questions:

- How should I organize game flow?
  Should I store game-state in database? Or can I have a class, e.g. Game, and store everything in it? Second option sounds easier, and more natural, but is it possible to implement it in an application with client-server async nature?
- How should client interact with server?
  I'd like the board state to be updated in real-time. Is js EventSource the best option here?
  Do I need anything beyond Sinatra application with its stream keyword? Do I need EventMachine?

Comment: I wasn't able to extrapolate if you wanted one global game or a server with rooms to join a game. Do you mind clarifying?

Comment: sure, it's about rooms. But for now only two users will be just fine.

Comment: I have no idea how to answer your second question but as far as your first is concerned, I think you should try writing it first to see the challenges you face and if you do/don't need a DB. When I tried writing a similar game I found that I needed a DB.